# Access properties of a bar chart created with JSDOM

Tags: node.js, jasmine, jsdom

I'm learning jsdom to test visualizations in node.js, but got trouble accessing the properties of the objects that are created using jsdom. Maybe you can help me?

**test.js:** (This is the class where I create the barChart that should be tested)

```
let jsdom 

try {
  jsdom = require('jsdom/lib/old-api.js'); // jsdom >= 10.x
} catch (e) {
  jsdom = require('jsdom'); // jsdom <= 9.x
}

// wrapped in jsdom:
exports.barChart = function () {

 let barProperties;

  let bar = jsdom.env(
    '<html><body></body></html>', ['http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js'],
    function (err, window) {
      let svg = window.d3.select('body').append('svg')
        .attr('height', '500')
        .attr('width', '500')

      svg.append('rect')
        .attr('x', 10)
        .attr('y', 10)
        .attr('width', 80)
        .attr('height', 80)
        .style('fill', 'orange')

      barProperties = window.d3.select('body').html();
      console.log(barProperties);
    }
  )
  return bar;
}
```

barProperties produces the output:

```
<script class="jsdom" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<svg height="500" width="500">
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="80" height="80" style="fill: orange;"></rect>
</svg>
```

**test-spec.js:** (here I'd like to access the "height" attribute of the svg from barProperties)

```
let test = require('../../javascripts/test')
let jsdom

try {
  jsdom = require('jsdom/lib/old-api.js'); // jsdom >= 10.x
} catch (e) {
  jsdom = require('jsdom'); // jsdom <= 9.x
}

describe('Test d3 with jasmine', function () {

  describe('the svg', function () {

    it('should be created', function () {
      expect(getSvg().attr('height')).toBe('500'); <--- this doesn't work
    });
  });

  function getSvg () {

    test.barChart();
  }
})
```

Error Message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined
```

So is there a way to export the jsdom window object from barProperties? Thank you so much!

Comment: What happens when you change it as,       `expect(test.barChart().getAttr('height')).toBe('500'); ` ?

Comment: Hey David, `expect(test.barChart().attr('height')).toBe('500');` says `TypeError: test.barChart(...).attr is not a function`. "getAttr" was wrong, my bad. Edited this in the question